# Heading with different adaptive lines

Tags: html, css

I would like to create headings with different sizes and with adaptive different kind of lines on their sides: 
one goes from the left to the right the other one from the right to the left.

How can I made it?

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/akyVkG) of the representation.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title-stripes">Title 1</h1><br />
  <h1 class="title-stripes">This is a bigger title</h1><br />
  <h1 class="title-stripes">Small</h1>
</div>
```

The background images of the stripes has both a triangle on their inner side, one go from the left to the right the other one from the right to the left.

**UPDATE** CodePen with the solution

Comment: not sure if I correctly understood the goal. You were looking for `background-position: right;` in the `.title-stripes:before` section? Then the images just need a width of maximum half the target area's width.

Comment: I would like to extend the two DIFFERENT stripes; one to the left and the other to the other side.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyvbAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
.title-stripes:before {
  background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/2ugnc53.png);
  right: 100%;
}
```

With:

```
.title-stripes:before {
  background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/346nxu8.png);
  right: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by adaptive. Sounds like an ideal job for SVG though. You should be able to create a couple SVGs and manipulate them according to your desired effect

Answer (score 0):

You need more markup. You need to set a `<span>` or something inside those header tags and then add styles to the span. Here is how I create my accent headers. They are responsive and flex with font sizes.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eyvbwp

HTML:

```
<h2 class="accent-double text-center"><span>Hello World</span></h2>
```

CSS [LESS]:

```
.accent-double {
overflow: hidden;
text-align:center;
 span{
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   &:before{
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 9999px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -2px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   }
   &:after{
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 9999px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -2px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It sounds good but mine before/after backgrounds are different images.. How can I manage it?

Comment: @paolopolix here you go, you just need to play with the width a little bit or get a new pattern to get rid of those traingles. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eyvbwp